WebStorm: Set the language of document tips
I'm using WebStorm for my development and I would like to set the language of the JavaScript documentation information in the code editor to Chinese. I have tried changing the IDE language settings and downloading some plugins, but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there a way I can get the JavaScript documentation information displayed in Chinese?
I really want to set the info language to Chinese.
You can refer to this image:


Sadly, no -- it's not yet implemented. The docs are taken from MDN, and the base docs come in English and shipped with the IDE (original WEB-48771 ticket).
It's possible that some "hack" exist that may allow to workaround this (e.g. replace downloaded doc content), but I'm not familiar with such.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49228 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress. So far it has only 1 initial vote, so it does not seem that this feature is in demand.

sadly！But thanks for your answer
